# Expand/Collapse Logic for FlatList items - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

React Native App with a simple FlatList.
Requirement: Dropdown arrow icon needs to be displayed only when message is more than 3 lines. Short messages will not have any arrow icon.

[image]

Current Logic - I am displaying the message with "opacity:0", then finding the number of lines using onTextLayout, then checking if number of lines is greater than 3. 
If number of lines is greater than 3, a state is set and arrow icon is displayed for that message.

```js
class FlatListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arrowClicked: false,
      length: false
    }
  }
  
  setFullLength(bool){
    this.setState({
      arrowClicked: !this.state.arrowClicked
    })
  }
    
  measureView(event, lines) {
    const line = event.nativeEvent.lines.length
    if (line > 3) {
      this.setState({ length: true})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={textContainer}>
        <View style={{opacity:0, height:0}}> 
          <Text onTextLayout={(event, lines) => this.measureView(event, lines)}>{message}</Text>
        </View>
        
        { arrowClicked === true ? (
            <Text>{message}</Text>
          ) : (
            <Text numberOfLines={3} onTextLayout={(event, lines) => this.measureView(event, lines)}>{message}</Text>
          )
        }

        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
          <View style={{width:200}}>
            <Text>{timestampToStr(createDate)}</Text>         
          </View>
          <View style={{position:'absolute', right:3}}>
            { length === true ? arrowClicked === true ? (
                <Icon type='materialicons' name='arrow-drop-up' size={33} onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength()}}  />
              ) : (
                <Icon type='materialicons' name='arrow-drop-down' size={33} onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength()}}  />
              ) : null
            }  
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Setting a component with "opacity:0" is not the correct way!!! How else can I get the number of lines?? Is there any other way I can implement this??? Please help.

**Updated Code:**
The below component  is my renderItem of FlatList

```
renderItem({item}) {
    return < FlatListItem item={item} onPress={() => {this.goToDetails(item)} />
  }


<FlatList
        ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}></View>}
        data={notifications}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
        refreshControl={this.refreshControl()}
         />
```

```
class FlatListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       max: [],
     num: []
    }
  }

  measureView(event, lines) {
      let { num } = this.state;
      num[index] = event.nativeEvent.lines.length;
      console.log(num[index])
      this.setState({ num });
  }

  setlenth = (index) => {
    let { max } = this.state;
    max[index] = this.state.num[index];
    this.setState({ max });
}


setNumberOfLines(e) {
  let { max } = this.state;
  max[index] = 3;
  this.setState({ max });
}



  render() {
    return (
     <View style={textContainer} onLayout={(e)=>this.setNumberOfLines(e)}>
              
        <Text numberOfLines={this.state.max[index]} onTextLayout={(event, lines) => this.measureView(event, lines)} style={[subTitle,{fontSize:normalizeFontSize(15),lineHeight:normalizeLineHeight(15)}]}>{alert}</Text>
              
          
       <View style={{position:'absolute', right:3}}>

              {this.state.num[index] > 3 ?
                            <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 30, width: 30,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center' }} onPress={() => this.setlenth(index)}>
                                <Icon name="arrow-drop-down" />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            :
                            null
                        }
              </View> 
  
}

}
```

Comment: what's the point of set opacity to 0, I don't see it related to your question which I think is get the number of line

Comment: In the first View, the style "textContainer" has a flex: 3 and paddingLeft: 15. So the message needs to fit in the container. Now i need to get the number of lines for each message. So I displayed the message with opacity:0 AND numberOfLines is not set to "3". Hence number of lines for the entire message will be determined. If number of lines is greater than "3" then state "length" is set to true. Using this I can set my arrow icon. Hope you understood my explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export default class App extends Component {
state = {
    num: [],
    max: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        let { max } = this.state;
        max[index] = 3;
        this.setState({ max });
        console.log(this.state.max)
    }
}

getlenth = (e, index) => {
    let { num } = this.state;
    num[index] = e.nativeEvent.lines.length;
    this.setState({ num });
}

setlenth = (index) => {
    let { max } = this.state;
    max[index] = this.state.num[index];
    this.setState({ max });
}


render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
                    <View style={{ margin: 5, padding: 10 }}>
                        <Text numberOfLines={this.state.max[index]} onTextLayout={(e) => this.getlenth(e, index)}>{item.text}</Text>
                        {this.state.num[index] > 3 ?
                            <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 30, width: 30,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center' }} onPress={() => this.setlenth(index)}>
                                <Icon name="arrow-down" />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            :
                            null
                        }
                    </View>
                }
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

*num[] is for number of lines in each flatlist item and max[] is for maximum lines to display.*

```
var data = [
{ text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eget risus faucibus tortor commodo lobortis. Fusce molestie massa venenatis, pellentesque nibh non, mollis diam. Cras vitae massa consequat, placerat dolor eu, blandit magna. Sed scelerisque, purus sed sollicitudin viverra, nisi eros pharetra ex, vitae sagittis urna elit sed urna. Cras rhoncus fringilla sapien id porttitor. Nunc auctor, lacus et vehicula dapibus, est mi imperdiet felis, quis eleifend purus lorem eu risus. Integer sapien lacus, ullamcorper ut sodales et, viverra vitae est.' },
{ text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' },
{ text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eget risus faucibus tortor commodo lobortis. Fusce molestie massa venenatis, pellentesque nibh non, mollis diam. Cras vitae massa consequat, placerat dolor eu, blandit magna. Sed scelerisque, purus sed sollicitudin viverra, nisi eros pharetra ex, vitae sagittis urna elit sed urna. Cras rhoncus fringilla sapien id porttitor. Nunc auctor, lacus et vehicula dapibus, est mi imperdiet felis, quis eleifend purus lorem eu risus. Integer sapien lacus, ullamcorper ut sodales et, viverra vitae est.' },
{ text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eget risus faucibus tortor commodo lobortis. Fusce molestie massa venenatis, pellent' }
```

]

*This is data*

Comment: it worked!!! AMAZING!!!! But I am facing one issue. I slightly changed the above code to fit my components. Logic works fine. But the arrow appears for a second and then disappears. I console.log "this.state.num[index]". the first render shows the correct index number. But again if I scroll down (I don't know why my flatlist renders so many times) I see that "this.state.num[index]" is changed to "3". Hence the arrow is disappearing. I will post my updated code. Please have a look and let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: try removing onLayout={(e)=>this.setNumberOfLines(e)} and set numer of lines in componentDidMount().

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do that much login to get this functionality. I have simple solution for this problem.

First replace this :

```js
{ arrowClicked === true ? (
    <Text>{message}</Text>
  ) : (
    <Text numberOfLines={3} onTextLayout={(event, lines) => this.measureView(event, lines)}>{message}</Text>
  )
}
```

with this line :

```js
<Text numberOfLines={this.state.arrowClicked ? null : 3}>{message}</Text>
```

This will render full line of description if arrow clicked, otherwise it will display 3 line of your text.

Now, replace this :

```js
<View style={{position:'absolute', right:3}}>
  { length === true ? arrowClicked === true ? (
      <Icon type='materialicons' name='arrow-drop-up' size={33} onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength()}}  />
    ) : (
      <Icon type='materialicons' name='arrow-drop-down' size={33} onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength()}}  />
    ) : null
  }  
</View>
```

with below code :

```js
<Icon type='materialicons' name={arrowClicked ? 'arrow-drop-up' : 'arrow-drop-down'} size={33} onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength()}}  />
```

This will toggle the state of `arrowClicked` and display the icon based on `arrowClicked` status.

Now, your whole code should look like this :

```js
class FlatListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arrowClicked: false,
    }
  }
  
  setFullLength(bool){
    this.setState({
      arrowClicked: !this.state.arrowClicked
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={textContainer}>
        <Text numberOfLines={this.state.arrowClicked ? null : 3}>{message}</Text>

        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
          <View style={{width:200}}>
            <Text>{timestampToStr(createDate)}</Text>         
          </View>
          <Icon type='materialicons' name={arrowClicked ? 'arrow-drop-up' : 'arrow-drop-down'} size={33} onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength()}}  />
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there `onTextLayout` have to keep if there is `line > 3`

Comment: No, no need to add `onTextLayout`. Just change the number of line.

Comment: Oh , I see. It's my mistake, it just need auto or 3 lines.

Comment: @Kishan But won't this display the arrow icon for every message? Even for the short message?

Comment: Yaa that't the problem @masalaDosa. I'll check if something solution for this.

Comment: Much Appreciated Kishan !!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the hidden `View` at all. The second Text component should run your `onTextLayout` callback and set the state which if changed will rerender with the arrow. I also cleaned up your `render` a little. I would also recommend not using `length` as a property, maybe `showArrowIcon` is a better description.

You can pass functions directly as a callback without calling them, this also works great when your function signature is the same as the callback. For example `onTextLayout={(event, lines) => this.measureLines(event, lines)}` is the same as `onTextLayout={this.measureLines}`

```
    render() {
        const { arrowClicked, length } = this.state;
        const messageProps = arrowClicked
            ? {}
            : {
                    numberOfLines: 3,
                    onTextLayout: this.measureView,
              };

        const iconName = arrowClicked ? "arrow-drop-up" : "arrow-drop-down";

        return (
            <View style={textContainer}>
                <Text {...messageProps}>{message}</Text>

                <View
                    style={{
                        flexDirection: "row",
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "space-between",
                    }}
                >
                    <View style={{ width: 200 }}>
                        <Text>{timestampToStr(createDate)}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ position: "absolute", right: 3 }}>
                        {length && (
                            <Icon
                                type="materialicons"
                                name={iconName}
                                size={33}
                                onPress={this.setFullLength}
                            />
                        )}
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't display the arrow icon for any of the item. Really thought this would work!!! :/

Comment: In this.measureView, the length is never set to "true" as the lines are never > 3.